# How to get multiple strings from input and store them in QStringList?

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, qtwidgets, qstringlist

I'm using Qt framework to create an employee interface, which stores information of an employee (ID, name, surname, skills, etc..)

In the widget interface I've used a `lineEdit` for everything, since I need to store string types of information, the only exception is `skills` parameter, that should be a list of strings.

In my `mainwindow.cpp`, I should store a list of different skills, not just one, and that's the error I'm getting when I use my function `addEmployee()`, because it needs a list of strings (skills), not one string.

I should use `QStringList skills`, but how do I tell if the user is inserting multiple skills , and how do I store that single output in a list?

```
void MainWindow::on_add_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QString id = ui->id_lineEdit->text();
    QString nome = ui->name_lineEdit->text();
    QString cognome = ui->surname_lineEdit->text();

    QString skills = ui->skills_lineEdit->text();
    //should be QStringList skills 
    //but how can I tell the user is inserting different skills? 

    manage.addEmployee(id.toStdString(),
                       name.toStdString(),
                       surname.toStdString(),
                       skills.toStdString());

    //'manage' refers to the class manageEmployee.h
    //I already implemented to use function addEmployee(id, name, surname, {skills});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit unrefined, but I will try my best to answer based on what I could follow.

```
void MainWindow::on_add_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QString id = ui->id_lineEdit->text();
    QString name = ui->name_lineEdit->text();
    QString surname = ui->surname_lineEdit->text();

    QString skills = ui->skills_lineEdit->text();
    QStringList skillsList = skills.split(","); // or ";", etc.

    std::list<std::string> skillsStdList;
    for (const QString& qstr : skillsList) {
        skillsStdList.push_back(qstr.toStdString());
    }

    manage.addEmployee(id.toStdString(), name.toStdString(), surname.toStdString(), skillsStdList);
}
```

So if you want the user to input list of skills, you wanna be splitting them using a delimiter as well.
Then you can pass the resulting `QStringList` to `.addEmployee` assuming it takes a fourth argument `std::list<std::string>`

By using a delimiter, you allow the user to enter multiple skills as a single input, which simplifies the interface. However, you should make sure to handle any errors that can arise from invalid input, such as an empty or malformed input string.

Edit: Code updated in mind with `QList<Qstring>` not supporting `toStdString` method

Comment: So I should use a delimiter like a 'comma' to differentiate all the set of skills one user can enter? Thanks very much

Comment: @Irene Exactly, and you you can change the delimiter to anything you want. Developers usually use `,` `|`, `;`